# React Native Tab Navigator: empty space at bottom of tab bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, bottomtabs

I'm using `react-navigation@4.0.10` and `react-native@0.63.5` in my React Native app, and when I use `createBottomTabNavigator`, there's a gap underneath the tab labels on iPhone 11 Pro. It does not do the same on iPhone 12. My code for the `TabNavigatorOptions` is as follows

```
const TabNavigatorOptions = {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: TabColors.activeColor,
        inactiveTintColor: TabColors.labelColor,
        bottomNavigationOptions: {
            labelColor: TabColors.labelColor,
            rippleColor: "white",
            shifting: false,
            activeLabelColor: TabColors.activeColor,
            backgroundColor: TabColors.backgroundColor
        },
        style: {
             height: 56, elevation: 8, position: 'absolute', left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0
        }
    }
        
}
```

[image]

I've tried adding `paddingBottom: 0` to the `style` object, but it makes no difference.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

UPDATE:
If I add a red background in `tabBarOptions -> style`, with `SafeAreaView` I get this:
[image]

and if I remove `SafeAreaView` I get this
[image]

Comment: Might be `SafeAreaView` that causes extra height. Not sure tho, need to see full source code of bottom tab bar

Comment: @Tarık Please see the `UPDATE` I added

Comment: @gkeenley yeah the problem is `SafeAreaView ` it adds some spacing from bottom and from top too, you can directly use `ScrollView` and you'll be fine

Comment: You probably had two `SafeAreaView` that are wrapping to the bottom tab bar. Make sure that you only have one. @chikabala He should use `SafeAreaView`in anyway

Comment: @Tarık he can use directly `marginBottom`

Answer (score 2):

The only [solution](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5836) I could find for now is to remove the bottom inset from SafeAreaView. It's not a good solution in my opinion but at least it works:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";

export default function App() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView 
          style={{ flex: 1 }} 
          forceInset={{ top: "always", bottom: "never" }}
      >
          <AppNavigator />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

And if you are using [react-native-safe-area-context](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView 
            style={{ flex: 1 }} 
            edges={["right", "top", "left"]}
        >
            <AppNavigator />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```